# Which computer components become legacy the quickest?

Tags: computer-building, desktop-computer

I'm planning on building a new computer, but money is sort of tight. I follow a few websites and occasionally find incredibly good deals on components. So, I'm considering slowly acquiring the parts over the next year, just snagging something when the price is right.

In order to do this, however, I'd want to know the rate at which various components become superseded by new models. If I knew that component X only had about a year until it was superseded by component Y, then I'd wait to purchase component X last and get the newest model available.

So, which computer components in your standard (high-end) Desktop are the quickest to be superseded by new models?

**Primary Uses of Computer**: gaming, some light programming, casual use (e.g., web browsing)

Comment: The answer depends on what are you going to use your computer for. If you are a gamer, for instance, new video cards models come out every day. But if you aren't a gamer you won't care about that. If you want to store a lot of information, maybe you would want to wait till the end before buying your HDD.

Comment: @drk.com.ar I added what I'll mostly be using the computer for. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Users' brains, I think... ;-)

Comment: The problem with the word Obsolete, its when Legacy is no longer useful.  and this cant really be answered.  Since CPUs are newly being crapped out every quarter and Graphics cards being spit out semi annually, the word Obsolete tends to falter on item pre XP era.

Comment: @Virusboy do you have a suggestion for a better term to use? I struggled with properly formulating the question, hopefully the intent is clear enough.

Comment: Unsupported or Legacy.

Comment: Just start saving money. You won't be able to use the computer until you have all parts anyway, and the same parts will be cheaper to buy later.

Answer (score 0):

Motherboards are considered the fasted to be considered Legacy.  There is a new better functioning model coming out every week or month.  And since Motherboards get the least love they will be the first to get the Legacy title.  But functionally wise, it'll work for a couple years.  The next thing to be tossed into the Legacy scrap pile is CPU chips.
Intel and AMD have a bad habit of crapping something out either every Quarter or Every 6 months and immediately putting older chips that have been out for a year in Legacy mode.  Graphics cards are next while every day a newer better more robust card does come out, legacy support doesn't start until year 5.  With supported updated starting to die in the last 3 years of production.